# Create unique field in MongoDB aggregate when grouping by two fields, and use for sorting

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

When aggregating a collection with the following pipeline stages

```js
let ap = [{
          $group: {
            _id: {
              year: { $year: '$itemDate' },
              month: { $month: '$itemDate' },
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        }]
```

I receive something like this...

```bash
[
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 9 }, count: 2 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 4 }, count: 232 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 3 }, count: 259 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 8 }, count: 12 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 1 }, count: 76 }
]
```

I would like to use an `$addFields` stage (or similar) such that my results would have a key and be sorted by year-month, like this

```bash
[
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 1 }, count: 76, key: '2022-01'},
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 3 }, count: 259, key: '2022-03'},
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 4 }, count: 232, key: '2022-04'},
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 8 }, count: 12, key: '2022-08'},
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 9 }, count: 2, key: '2022-09'},
]
```

I have tried a template string, but it does not work. I also don't know how this would be sortable either...

```js
ap.push({
  $addFields: {
    key: `${'$_id.year'}-${'$_id.month'}`,
    key2: '$_id.year',
   },
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try sorting by `{itemDate: 1}` prior to grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$concat` to chain up the result from `$toString`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "key": {
        "$concat": [
          {
            "$toString": "$_id.year"
          },
          "-",
          {
            "$toString": "$_id.month"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      key: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tZx6LTQu4zn)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3-step aggregation pipeline using `$project`, `$group` and `$sort`. It can look something like this:

```
[
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': true, 
      'itemDate': true, 
      'key': {
        '$concat': [
          {
            '$toString': {
              '$year': '$itemDate'
            }
          }, '-', {
            '$toString': {
              '$month': '$itemDate'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$key', 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'key': -1
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

You don't need a separate key to sort. Just sort on `_id.year` and `_id.month`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: {$year: "$itemDate"},
        month: {$month: "$itemDate"},
        
      },
      count: {$sum: 1}
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.year": 1,"_id.month": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MYxIodYaA8y)

---

Option 2:

Instead of having another stage, create the field in $group stage itself. Convert the date to string and pick the $first from the group.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: {$year: "$itemDate"},
        month: {$month: "$itemDate"},
        
      },
      count: {$sum: 1},
      key: {
        $first: {
          $dateToString: {date: "$itemDate", format: "%Y-%m"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "key": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aFV_O-FcltS)